# How to use string methods on the key in Map.get()

Tags: javascript

I have a created a new Map where I am setting several paths to be true or false.

```
const pathMap = new Map();
pathMap.set(currentPath, true);  //f.e. pathMap.set('ROOT/FOLDER_1', true);
```

I am trying to retrieve the values using the `Map.prototype.get()` method, however I have the constraint that I do not know the full path, but only the last part of it. I have tried to use string methods but either get the error that 'key' or endsWith is not defined.

```
pathMap.get(key.endsWith('FOLDER_1'));
pathMap.get(endsWith('FOLDER_1'));
```

So my question is whether it is somehow possible to access the key using `Map.get()` to apply string methods or if I have to iterate over the Map?

Comment: A map requires a specific string as far as i know, you cannot do what you aim to do in this manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the whole Map and filter for all the elements whose key ends with the expected string:

```
for (const [key, value] of pathMap.entries()) {
    if (key.endsWith('FOLDER_1')) {
        console.log(key, value);
        …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all keys which ends with the given last part.

After, you can get the value by using one of these key.

```
const keys = Array.from(pathMap.keys()).filter(key => key.endsWith('FOLDER_1'));
let value = pathMap.get(keys[0]);
```

EDIT: as Bergi said, Map.keys return an iterator, not an array. 
It's why we use the Array.from method.

Comment: `pathMap.keys()` returns an iterator, not an array, so it won't have a `filter` method. You'd need to use `Array.from(pathMap.keys()).filter(…)`